# React D3 error 404 when importing a .csv file

Tags: reactjs, csv, webpack, d3.js, next.js

I'm trying to use `csv` from `d3` to render some data in my Next.js application. Following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OacqgtI30pk), I got a 404 error. I've searched a lot, and as it's showed in the video, it's possible to use `csv` with React. Here is my code

```
import {csv} from 'd3';
import datacsv from './test.csv';

class Power extends Component {
...
        componentDidMount() {

            csv(datacsv).then(data=>{
                console.log(data);
          
              });

        }
...
```

I've double-checked the path to the file.

**Note.**
I've seen some questions in StackOverflow about this topic but they refer to Node.js or are not answered.

Comment: 404 means file not found. Are you sure 'test.csv' is there?

Comment: Yeah I know, I double checked the file path and its name. If the file is not at `./test.csv` I would have a `module import error`,  but it’s not my case

Comment: what happend if you just fetch() the file? Get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.csv` expects a URL to be passed, not a file path or module.

You can move the `test.csv` file to your `public/` folder as to provide a valid location for `d3.csv()` to fetch the data from, then point to it.

```js
import { csv } from 'd3';

class Power extends React.Component {
    // ...
    csv('/test.csv').then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to read the `.csv` file from the file system in your  Next.js app, you'll need to install `csv-loader` and add it to your `next.config.js`'s webpack config.

```sh
$ npm install csv-loader
```

```js
// next.config.json

module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.csv$/,
            loader: 'csv-loader',
            options: {
                dynamicTyping: true,
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true
            }
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

You can then load the `test.csv` file directly, without having to use `d3.csv`.

```js
import datacsv from './test.csv';

class Power extends React.Component {
    // ...
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(datacsv);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you! Both ways work